non-homogeneous wave PDE with mixed boundary conditions
I'm working on a partial differential equation given by:
$$ u_{tt} = u_{xx} + F(x,t), \quad 0 \leq x < 1, \; t > 0 $$
with the initial conditions:
$$ u(x,0) = f(x), \quad u_t(x,0) = g(x), \quad 0 \leq x < 1 $$
and the boundary conditions:
$$ u(0,t) = 0; \quad a u(1,t) + b u_x(1,t) = 0, \quad a,b > 0 $$
Part (a): I've already used the energy integral method to show that the solution to this problem is unique. Specifically, I considered the difference of two potential solutions and showed that the resulting energy integral must be zero, leading to the conclusion that the two solutions are identical.
Part (b): Now, I need to solve the PDE using the method of separation of variables, and I've been considering a few approaches:

Periodic Extension to $\mathbb{R}$: I was thinking of extending the problem periodically to the entire real line to make the problem more tractable. However, I'm unsure if this approach is suitable given the mixed boundary conditions.

Splitting the Solution: I thought about splitting the solution as $ u(x,t) = v(x,t) + w(x,t) $, where $ v(x,t) $ satisfies the homogeneous PDE with non-homogeneous boundary conditions, and $ w(x,t) $ accounts for the non-homogeneous PDE with simpler boundary conditions. My idea was to solve for $ v(x,t) $ first and then handle $ w(x,t) $, potentially using Duhamel's principle to incorporate the non-homogeneous term $ F(x,t) $.

Duhamel's Principle: Since $ F(x,t) $ introduces a non-homogeneous term, I’m considering using Duhamel’s principle to construct the full solution after solving the homogeneous problem. However, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed with this in the context of the boundary conditions.


I would appreciate any guidance on whether these approaches are appropriate and how to effectively apply them. Specifically, how should I handle the periodic extension and the decomposition of the solution, and is Duhamel’s principle the right tool for solving the non-homogeneous problem in this context?
